# TexWorks syntax custom highlight for text within curly braces

Tags: texworks, syntax-highlighting

I would like to have the text between curly braces appear highlighted in lightpink in my TexWorks editor.  I don't have a cs background, and this is as far as I've got.  I've added the following to my syntax-patterns file:

```
lightpink   N   /\{([^}]+)\}/g
```

but it does not appear to work.  My question is two parts:

1. Is this even doable?  I sometimes have expressions between curly braces, for example

   ```
   \index{\textit{thyme}}
   ```

   Ideally I'd like only "thyme" to appear in light pink.  There's already default syntax color for `\index`, `{`, `\textit`, and `}}`.
2. If this is doable, what should my regular expression be?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I know nothing about TexWorks, but your regular expression won't work in general. It doesn't handle nested braces like `{abc{pqr}xyz}` - it will match `{abc{pqr}`. I don't think a RE can do this, because the RE can't "count" the number of nested `{`'s and skip over the correct number of `}`'s.

Comment: I see.  I'm sorry, I don't have a cs background.  Is it possible to just highlight anything between a { and }?  As in if there's a {, look to see if it's eventually followed by a }, and if so, select that text?